# jquery calendar issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a start and stop textbox field which triggers jquery calendar. I want to know whether it is possible to achieve when I select a date on the start, will populate the same on the stop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `onSelect` callback to copy the start date into end date field.

```
$('#startDate').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
      $('#endDate').val($(this).val());
   }
});
```

**EDIT::**

```
$('#startDate).datetimepicker({
      ampm: true, 
      minDate: 0,
      onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
          $('#endDate').val($(this).val());
       }
});
```

**EDIT for end date::**

```
$('#endDate).datetimepicker({ ampm: true });
```

the two edits combined will make your entire code. Also you may want to add a if condition in `onSelect` to check if there is a value already in `endDate` so that you won't accidentally overwrite it.

Comment: @ Teja Kantamneni -- sorry, would datetimepicker have the same effect as what you described? I did get an alert when I select a date but still no luck.

$('#startDate).datetimepicker({ ampm: true, minDate: 0 });
        $('#endDate).datetimepicker({ ampm: true });

        $('#startDate).datetimepicker({
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                alert("ON");
                $('#endDate).val($(this).val());
            }
        });

Comment: you don't need two bindings on the startDate. both of them can be combined to one. Check the edit

Comment: @ Teja -- ok, this gets me on the right track but now this wont let me select a date in the end date field if I wanted to change it. For example click in the end date field to bring up the calendar.

Comment: You have to bind one more picker to end date too. Check edit one more time

Comment: @ Teja Kantamneni -- for start date if I select 08/20/2010 with a time of 9:00 am, my end date only returns 08/20/2010. Do you have any idea why it isnt giving me the time also?

Comment: @hersh -- can you post your HTML and js code so far. Preferably in http://jsfiddle.net/